# MVC Ajax form not working with dropdown list Item change event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-ajax

I have a MVC Ajax form. I am trying to send Ajax request to the controller by changing the items in dropdown list. I tried with the below code, but my controller treated request as normal not Ajax request.

View:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CashReceipt", "Admin",null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updateContainer" }, new { @class = "smart-form",@id="ajaxform" }))
 {   
List<SelectListItem> sli = new List<SelectListItem>() 
{ 
new SelectListItem { Text = "Paid", Value = "Paid" }, 
new SelectListItem { Text = "Unpaid", Value = "Unpaid" 
} };
<label class="select">
@Html.DropDownList("Filter", new SelectList(sli, "Text", "Value", ViewBag.Filter), "--",   new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
<i></i>
</label>
}
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CashReceipt(string Filter="")
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_CashReceipt", model);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Ajax request is identified in the controller with the button click event but not dropdown list on change. Why? Please provide a way to achieve this task with dropdown list item change.

Can anybody help me regarding this problem?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CashReceipt", "Admin",null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updateContainer" }, new { @class = "smart-form",@id="ajaxform" }))
 {   
List<SelectListItem> sli = new List<SelectListItem>() 
{ 
new SelectListItem { Text = "Paid", Value = "Paid" }, 
new SelectListItem { Text = "Unpaid", Value = "Unpaid" 
} };

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

<label class="select">
@Html.DropDownList("Filter", new SelectList(sli, "Text", "Value", ViewBag.Filter), "--",   ) 
/* Here I removed new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" } */
<i></i>
</label>
}
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CashReceipt(string Filter="")
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_CashReceipt", model);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It may helpful to someone.

```
new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" }
```